# what does re-assigning a variable in a for loop in JS mean?

Tags: javascript

I have been struggling with coding for a while, functions seem perfectly fine but loops are painful.

I understand this one very well, except for the one line that starts with j=i, what is it referring to?

```
text = "Blah blah blah blah blah blah Eric \
blah blah blah Eric blaeh blah Eric blah blah \
blah blah blah blah blah Eric";

var myName = "Eric";
var hits = [];


for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
if (text[i] === "E") {



    for(var j = i; j < (myName.length + i); j++) {
        hits.push(text[j]);
      }
   }
 }

if (hits.length === 0) {
console.log("Your name wasn't found!");
} else {
console.log(hits);
}
```

Comment: Start inner loop from current iteration of outer loop.

Comment: sorry I'm a rookie here and started programming few days ago, would you please elaborate with a less technical language?

Comment: Your inner loop `j` begins at whatever iteration the outer loop (`i`) is currently on. So if `i` = 1, `j` will start counting up from 1

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your concert: j and i are merely placeholders for the indexes that the loop will run through. When the second for loop assigns j to i, once the first for loop loops through, the second for loop will start on the index (the location in the text) where i left off from the first for loop.

Answer (score 0):

The outside loop, the one that defints `var i = 0`, is looping over the character indexes of the text string. For each character index the if statement checks if it is an "E". When `i` is 30  the character at index 30 of your string (`text[i]`) is the first E. The if returns true and runs the code in the braces. At this point it starts a new loop and `j` is set equal to `i` (which is 30) and the sub-loop runs while `j` is less than your names length (4) plus `i` (30), or, 34. Each iteration of that sub loop pushes a letter at the index of `j` (`text[j]`) into a `hits`.

Answer (score 0):

It means for every iteration of you outer loop (or the `i` loop) the `j` variable will initially have the value of your `i` variable. So, for the first iteration of your outer loop, `i` is `0` so `j` is initially `0`, on the second iteration `i` is `1` so `j` get reinitialized to `1`. And so on.

Answer (score 0):

The following definition of for loop is taken from [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp).

> for (statement 1; statement 2; statement 3) {
>        code block to be executed  }
>
> Statement 1 is executed before the loop (the code block) starts.
>
> Statement 2 defines the condition for running the loop (the code
>   block).
>
> Statement 3 is executed each time after the loop (the code block) has
>   been executed.

In your case, `var j=i` is executed before the loop, so that `text[j]` will on start be `text[i]` and the, each time `j` is increased, `text[j]` will be an element that comes after `text[i]`.

Therefore, the iteration goes `text[i]` -> `text[i+1]` -> ... -> `text[myName.length + i - 1]`