# javascript Your second "for" loop

Tags: javascript

```
var text = "Hello world Keya how you doing Keya";

var myName ="Keya";
var hits = [];
for(var i=0; i<text.length; i++ )
{
if (text[i]=== 'K')
{
    for (var j=i; j< i+ myName.length; j++)
    {

          hits.push(text[j]);
    }
  }
}
```

---

I don't understand what is `hits.push`

secondly, I don't know

```
for (var j=i; j< i+ myName.length; j++)
```

Comment: You tried googling these things? Some search queries: `javascript push`, `javascript for loop`, `javascript arrays`

Comment: So really what you're saying is that you don't understand javascript, and should get a book ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34951310/what-does-re-assigning-a-variable-in-a-for-loop-in-js-mean/34955348#34955348

Comment: I don't understand what is hits.push

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does it matter which equals operator (== vs ===) I use in JavaScript comparisons?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons)

Comment: please move the `if` block inside the first `for` block.

Comment: for `push`, try Googling "MDN push". MDN is a great site which will answer many of these questions for you. For the `for` statement, you could google "MDN for".

Comment: To close voters: this question may not be very useful, which means you can choose to downvote it if you so desire. However, it is not too broad, or otherwise off-topic. Please follow the reasons given for close votes; they're there for a reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code for the `myName` variable which is in this case '`Keya`' in the string `text` .

`hits` variable store the name as an array.

- `for(var i=0; i<text.length; i++ )` Run through the string
- `if (text[i]=== 'K')` If `text[i]` is the first letter of your name (it would be more flexible if you change it to `name[0]`)
- `for (var j=i; j< i+ myName.length; j++)` Run through the string starting for from i (the index the first letter in the `name` found in `text`) to `i+ the length of the name`
- `hits.push(text [j])` Add text[j] to the array ( see [JavaScript Array push() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp) )

Answer (score 0):

```
   var text = "vinod kumar";
    var myName = text;
    hits = []

    for(i=0; i < text.length; i++) {
        if(text[i] == "u") {
            for(var j=i; j < (myName.length+i); j++ ) {
                hits.push(text[j]);
            }
        }
    }
```